# Loop over network interfaces and extract MAC addresses via Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate - I've found some similar questions online but could not quite get any to work.

I'm trying to create a playbook that finds all available network intefaces on a server, and then loop over them and extracts each interface's MAC address. I'd then like Ansible to print a message to the user.

Finding all interfaces was fairly straightforward:

```
  - name: Find NICs
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: Found network interface {{ item }}
    with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_interfaces }}"
```

This outputs the interface's name in the OS - strings such as `ens123`, `enp456` and so forth.

Finding the MAC was also quite simple:

```
  - name: Find NICs MAC
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts[' {{ item }}']['macaddress'] }}"
    with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_interfaces }}"
```

Now, the `{{ item }}` variable is meant to be the found interface name (ex: `ens123`).
If I replace it with the actual name every time, the command works.

I'm also aware that this is likely a simple task via shell, but it is meant to work across a wide range of systems and so I'm trying an Ansible-only solution.

I've pored over the documentation and could not figure it out - any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this ``msg: "{{ ansible_facts[item]['macaddress']|default(None) }}"``

Comment: A good read: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names

Comment: Thank you both! Vladimir, your answer worked perfectly. Zeitounator - That seems to be exactly the doc I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I rolled back your tagging of the question as "(solved)" in the title. If the issue has a solution, please post an answer below. You then have the option to _accept_ that answer (or any other answer that happens to appear).  When a question has an accepted answer, the issue is properly marked as resolved.  You are definitely allowed to answer your own questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as Vladimir suggested above, was the following:

```
msg: "{{ ansible_facts[item]['macaddress']|default(None) }}"
```

Whole block:

```
  - name: Find NICs MAC
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: " interface {{ item }}'s MAC is {{ ansible_facts[item]['macaddress']|default(None) }}"
    with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_interfaces }}"
```